# Manually Calling an event function using JQuery

Tags: jquery, function

I want to know if their is an option to call a function that is already assigned to a JQuery event.

For example:

`$("#somediv").change(function() { //do something });`

I want to be able to manually call that function that was originally assigned to the "somediv" element.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try if(typeof ($("#somediv").change) == 'function') { yourCode(); $("#somediv").change(); }

Comment: @jernej: I don't think that will do what you want; `$("#somediv").change` is going to give you the function `change` of the jQuery object, not your function.

Comment: @jernej `typeof ($("#somediv").change)` will **always** be `'function'` with jQuery.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$("#somediv").trigger("change");
```

Comment: N.B. this is equivalent to `$("#somediv").change();`

Comment: Note: For both plain objects and DOM objects other than window, if a triggered event name matches the name of a property on the object, jQuery will attempt to invoke the property as a method if no event handler calls event.preventDefault(). If this behavior is not desired, use .triggerHandler() instead.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/trigger

Answer (score 23):

Have you tried this?

```
$("#somediv").change();
```

Answer (score 4):

JQuery can trigger a given event; just call `$("#somediv").change()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you meant to do is define the function outside change(..).

```
function whatever() { // do something }

$("#somediv").change(whatever);
```

Then you can call your function elsewhere.

At least that's how I interpreted your question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of achieving this is placing the "actual" function outside the Jquery call. So, your code would look something like:

```
$("#somediv").change(function() { doSomething(); });

var doSomething = function() {
// actually do something
}
```

This would make it quite simple to call the doSomething function form anywhere in your scripts.

Comment: Nice idea. You would probably need to pass $(this) into the doSomething function though using your example as in my situation i wanted to do something  using the attributes of the #somediv

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to actualy trigger the change event (as shown in the previous answers above), you should probably extract that function into something that you can call from multiple places. It looks like you have found a place where reuse is in your application and extracting it may be the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    $("#somediv").change();
}
</script>
```

i think this what you want to do .